# Bitmap image array from recyclerview to other activity with position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-bitmap

****I want to get single image from bitmap array recycler view and show it to my detail activity****

[recycler view adapter class]
'
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

```
    model model= list.get(position);

    byte[] image=list.get(position).getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);

    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    holder.t1.setText(list.get(position).getBrand());
    holder.t2.setText(list.get(position).getModel());
    holder.t3.setText(list.get(position).getYear());
    holder.t4.setText(list.get(position).getPrice());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent= new Intent(context,cardetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("im",bitmap);
            intent.putExtra("branddetail", String.valueOf(list.get(position).getBrand()));
            intent.putExtra("modeldetail",String.valueOf(list.get(position).getModel()));
            intent.putExtra("yeardetail",String.valueOf(list.get(position).getYear()));
            intent.putExtra("pricedetail",String.valueOf(list.get(position).getPrice()));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

[detailactivity]

```
ImageView imgview;
TextView t1,t2,t3,t4;

Bitmap bitmap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardetail);


    imgview=findViewById(R.id.imgdetail);
    t1=findViewById(R.id.cname);
    t2=findViewById(R.id.cmodel);
    t3=findViewById(R.id.cyear);
    t4=findViewById(R.id.cprice);

    listadaptr listadaptr;
    Bitmap bitmap= getIntent().getParcelableExtra("im");
    imgview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    
    t1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("branddetail"));
    t2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("modeldetail"));
    t3.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("yeardetail"));
    t4.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("pricedetail"));
```

enter code here

Comment: `I want to get single image from bitmap array recycler view ` Yes ok. do it. What is the problem? There is no problem description. Nor a question.

Comment: I have multiple images in my recyclerview fetched from sqlite using bitmap. I want to take particular image from recyclerview by onclick to other activity and show that in full screen. I don't know how to do that

Comment: Well you have a lot of code in that on click handler. It looks as if that is exactly what you need. If it does not work then you should tell what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an interface with a method

```
void onImageChosen(Bitmap bitmap)
```

which will send the image to activity where RecyclerView is added.

```
listener.onImageChosen(yourBitmap);
```

**but it would be better to send path of image instead of full Bitmap.**
And I don't understand the purpose of your Intent.

When you've already got the Bitmap from RecyclerView and it's in your Activity you can pass it.
To send an existing Bitmap from one Activity to another you can:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

To get:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Comment: The intent purpose is to show the detail of the clicked position. I have many items in my recyclerview when i click any of them the intent should take the details of that particular position to the next activity

Comment: @sameeryawar I edited my answer, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I put the intent into bundle and it resolved thanks guys.

Comment: Can you show the code ?